# console.log doesn't work with react-native

Tags: react-native, logging, console.log

I'm starting with react-native and I'm getting this problem: I can't log to bundler metro server.

If I create my application using `create-react-native-app`, I can do 'console.log' and value are logged to metro bundler (running on port 8081).

But if I create my application with `react-native init <project>`, this doesn't work. To make `console.log` work, I need to open Chrome DevTools and set remote debug in application.

So my question is: is there any way to make native code to log in bundler console with console.log? I don't want to work with 'create-react-native-app' because it uses Expo and 'realm' database doesn't support expo.

I've tried with react-native 0.55.4 and 0.56, both in windows and linux.

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-log-ios, it works without remote JS debugging!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can also see the *console.log()* outputs using these commands:

```
$ react-native log-android
$ react-native log-ios
```

**Note:** It also works to debug native errors, for example when you have a blank screen and metro bundler doesn't show errors neither.

For more information you can [check this out](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-console-logs)

Comment: `Command log-android unrecognized. Make sure that you have run npm install and that you are inside a react-native project.`

Kindly, could you explain me what's the problem?

Comment: Does not work for me, I only see generic React Native log messages, such as `Initializing React Xplat Bridge.`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'm i MacOS and I've installed react native with "npm install react-native", and the command "react-native log-android" show me some thing similar to Metro but it doesn't show the console.log output.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if I correctly understand your question (because of my english), but you can try this:

> Run adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V in a terminal to see
>   your Android app's logs.

Taken from [Using adb logcat for React Native Debugging](https://medium.com/@taufiq_ibrahim/using-adb-logcat-for-react-native-debugging-38256bda007c)

Answer (score 1):

You can download React Native Debugger and Open your JS Debugger in development menu. You can see everything into RN Debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that console.log are omitted from console log if your disable remote debug from the debug menu

Answer (score 1):

On Mac. While on ios simulator Clicked on

> Command-d->Stop Debugging

.This made logging work for me.